# How to make a AJAX website crawlable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

The following website is a good example of a crawlable AJAX website (HTML5 + CSS3 + AJAX) using history.pushState():

http://html5.gingerhost.com/

(for background see https://moz.com/blog/create-crawlable-link-friendly-ajax-websites-using-pushstate)

However, this website assumes that the dynamic content can be rendered server side at page load. For example, if you land directly on http://html5.gingerhost.com/seattle, the content related to Seattle is not loaded through AJAX, it's already in the page.

Let's assume that the content can only be loaded through AJAX calls. How can I make such a website crawlable ?

My specific goal is to make this website crawlable:
http://code-exercises.com/programming/

At the moment, all programming exercises are loaded through AJAX. I would like to have programming/easy/exercise-number-one.

My website is served by an NGINX instance that serves static content and forwards all AJAX request to a Tomcat instance.

Comment: "Let's assume that the content can only be loaded through AJAX calls. How can I make such a website crawlable ?" — Poorly. And that's a false assumption, which usually comes down to not wanting to make the effort.

Comment: "I would consider solutions to render the content … server side." contradicts "Let's assume that the content can only be loaded through AJAX calls."

Comment: @Quentin currently my content is only available through RESTful calls, I would consider solutions to render this content server side but I don't know how to do it. I would consider solution to render the content both server and client side.

Comment: Pick a server side programming language. Replicate the work of the client side code.

Comment: @Quentin I see your point, but I still would like to use AJAX for performance reasons, similar to what's been done on http://html5.gingerhost.com/

Comment: So do that. You linked to an article which shows you how to use pushState and Ajax to build on top of a robust server rendered site.

Comment: Question is best answered by reading the various search engine specifications for ajax driven sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: The Easy One, use prerender.io

Option 2: in your app build process include a Phantom.js to make static versions of your pages

Option 3: if you use Angular, you can migrate to angular2, or other framework with server-side rendering

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how to make a angular app crawlable.

Basically, you will have to have a cached version of the page with the data loaded that will be served to web crawlers.

https://prerender.io/ this is an example of it.